# IIS windows authentication alternatives

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

For a .NET 1.1 website that I just moved, there is a folder that was password protected from IIS (6) using windows authentication. The new server is running IIS 7 and the host does not want to install basicAuthentication or windowsAuthentication roles because it's a shared server. What other alternatives are there to protecting this folder? It only needs a single username/password and doesn't need any special management.

I thought I saw IIS 7 had it's own users and authentication system, is this a viable option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put security in the web.config on a particular folder for a user, set of users, or a role:

[Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)

Comment: Additional development was unwanted, but since we can't change the server in anyway, this was how it had to be. Just hard coded a forms auth setup. didnt take that long as was faster than trying to find another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This TechNet article about [Configuring Authentication in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010%28WS.10%29.aspx) is definitely worth reading.

Comment: Been over this, they all require installing basciAuthentication role which is not possible due to the host.

Comment: I beg to disagree, neither _Anonymous Authentication Identity_ nor _Impersonation Authentication_ require the `BasicAuth` module as those use their own (`AnonymousAuthModule` and `ManagedEngine` respectively).

For _Anonymous Authentication Identity_ its as simple as this one liner:

`appcmd set config /section:anonymousAuthentication /userName: Moe /password: pssword1`

Comment: yes you are correct. But how do these options protect the folder?

Comment: This might help: [Enable Anonymous Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731244(WS.10).aspx)